# Trying to make a dice rolling script in python

Tags: python

I'm getting a vague syntax error with the print int(rollval) on line 15.

```
from random import randint
roll == 0
def diceroll(roll):
    def dicenum(userdicenum):
        userdicenum = int(raw_input("How many dice would you like to roll?"))
        return userdicenum

    def dicesides(userdiceside):
        userdiceside = int(raw_input("How many sides for each die?"))
        return userdiceside


    for rollval in range(1,userdicenum):
        rollval = randint(1,userdiceside)
        print int(rollval)
        roll = roll + rollval
        return roll
    print roll
```

Comment: what python version are you using? if it's 3+ you need parenthesis on the print

Comment: "vague syntax error" - Well, what error did you get?

Comment: @Alessandro I am using 3. How exactly do the parenthesis need to be?

Comment: @BlackThunder this is my first time working on a project that isn’t a lesson out of a book. Could you explain to me why this is bad?

Comment: @Broman it just says invalid syntax point to the int

Comment: Its `input()` and `print("abc")` in python3 not `raw_input()` and `print "abc"`

Comment: where does userdicenum in the for loop come from?

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import randint
def diceroll():
    def dicenum():
        userdicenum = int(input("How many dice would you like to roll?"))
        return userdicenum

    def dicesides():
        userdiceside = int(input("How many sides for each die?"))
        return userdiceside

    roll = 0
    dicesida = dicesides() # so you dont have to re type it =)
    for rollval in range(dicenum()):
        rollval = randint(1,dicesida)
        print(int(rollval))
        roll = roll + rollval
    return roll
print(diceroll())
```

is this what you want?

Comment: one more fix: `roll == 0` is `roll = 0` in line 2

Comment: i dont think that line is needed at all actualy

Comment: You have also not fixed `raw_input`

Comment: I will also suggest to start the loop from range `0`. Try the code.

Answer (score 0):

One difference between Python3 and Python2 is that in Python3, the print statement is a function in Python3, but a keyword in Python2. The fact that it is a function means that you have to use it like any other function, which is by putting the arguments within parenthesis.

Use `print(int(rollval))`

You should also have a look at the second line. `roll == 0` should probably be `roll = 0`. And as mentioned in comments, you should also not use `raw_input` in Python3. Use `input`.